# Find form field length in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have following code for finding length of submitted form field length.

```
exports.changeStatus = function(req, res) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
var access_token=req.body.access_token;
var status=req.body.statuse;
var access_token_aray=new Array();
var respon="";
var errorcode="";   
connection.query('Select `access_token`,`status` from `userss`',function(err,row,field){


    if((access_token.length==0)||(status.length==0)){
        respon="Please fill all the fields.";
        errorcode=100;
    }

    /*else if(access_token_aray[access_token]!==1){
        respon="Invalid access_token";
        errorcode=101;
    }
    */
    if(errorcode){
        respon = {"error" : respon, "error-code" : errorcode};
    }
    /*
    else{
        respon = {"log" : 1, "access_token" :access_token };
    }       
        */
    res.send(JSON.stringify(respon,0,4)); 


});
```

But it is giving me following errror

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Query._callback (/home/group3/www/friends/routes/status.js:23:19)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/home/group3/www/friends/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:78:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/home/group3/www/friends/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:143:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (/home/group3/www/friends/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:127:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/group3/www/friends/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:197:24)
    at Parser.write (/home/group3/www/friends/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:62:12)
    at Protocol.write (/home/group3/www/friends/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:37:16)
    at Socket.ondata (stream.js:51:26)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:720:14)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It clearly says :

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Check whether your request.body has statuse and access_token like `console.log(request.body.statuse).`